# Add Dynamic Comments In Magento 2.1x

Tags: magento2, system.xml, system-configuration

I am trying to display a **comment** on a `system.xml` field based on the **results from a function**,
This is what i have so far in my `Vendor/Module/etc/system.xml`

```
<group id="optional_configuration" module="vendor_module" translate="label" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="20">
    <label>Optional Configuration</label>
    <frontend_model>Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Fieldset</frontend_model>
    <field id="option_1" translate="label" module="vendor_module" type="select" sortOrder="13" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
        <label>Initial Option</label>
        <enable>1</enable>
        <source_model>Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\Custom</source_model>
        <comment> <model>vendor_module/field_comment</model></comment>


    </field>
</group>
```

In my `Vendor/Module/Model/Field/Comment.php` I have:

```
class Vendor_Module_Model_Field_Comment
{
    public function getCommentText()
    {
        //do some calculations here
        return 'Some string based on the calculations';
    }
}
```

After executing this nothing shows on the module's admin page and this is error in my `var/log/system.log`:

> main.CRITICAL: Class vendor_module/field_comment does not exist [] []

Can anyone help me out, I am new to Magento development

Answer (score 1):

Try following way:

Change your comment tag by

```
<comment><model>Vendor\Module\Model\Comment</model></comment>
```

And your model class should be

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

class Comment implements \Magento\Config\Model\Config\CommentInterface
{
    /**
     * Retrieve element comment by element value
     * @param string $elementValue
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCommentText($elementValue)
    {
        //do some calculations here
        return 'Some string based on the calculations';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

create adminhtml/system.xml file in the Magento module

- List item

reference or create some section and group of the system config

add the field to the all the required nodes. Add following sub-node to the field

create ModelFQN which implements Magento\Config\Model\Config\CommentInterface.
Return string out of getCommentText() which will show up in the comment section.

**to change in system.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="dev">
            <group id="debug">
                <field id="graphql_enabled" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enable Sample</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                    <comment model="Magento\Sample\Model\Comment" />
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

**in model :**

```
namespace Magento\Sample\Model;
use \Magento\Config\Model\Config\CommentInterface;
class Comment implements CommentInterface
{
    public function getCommentText($elementValue)  //the method has to be named getCommentText
    {
        //do some calculations here
        return $elementValue . 'Some string based on the calculations';
    }
}
```

The core modules never used it:

Thanks,
[Magento Developer](https://magnetoitsolutions.com/services/hire-dedicated-magento-developer)

Answer (score 0):

**Add into system.xml file**

```
<field id="row_payment_us_free" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="5" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" canRestore="1">
    <label>Payment US Free</label>
    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
    <comment><model>VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\SystemConfigComment</model></comment>
</field>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Model**

**SystemConfigComment.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model;

use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

class SystemConfigComment implements \Magento\Config\Model\Config\CommentInterface
{
    protected $urlInterface;

    public function __construct(
        UrlInterface $urlInterface
    ) {
        $this->urlInterface = $urlInterface;
    }

    public function getCommentText($elementValue)
    {
        $url = $this->urlInterface->getUrl('adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/payment');

        return 'Require to enable <a href="' .$url . '#row_payment_us_free" target="_blank">Zero Subtotal Checkout</a>payment method for Zero Subtotal order.';
    }
}
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***